# update query with insertion?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i need a query which have to do both update and insert..

first i have to check this condition

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM NEC_Customer_DB_Map where DB_AvailabilityFlag = 'Y'
```

and if `DB_AvailabilityFlag = 'Y'` i have to update this `'Y'` as `'ASSIGNED'` and also i
have to insert by using

```
 INSERT INTO NEC_Customer_DB_Map(NEC_CustomerCode,NEC_CustomerName) VALUES(@NEC_CustomerCode,@NEC_CustomerName)
```

can anyone combine these into one query..Any Suggestion?

Comment: 1. Are you saying that you should only do the `insert` if the update succeeds? If not why are you bothering trying to combine them? If so I'd just do the Update and check `@@ROWCOUNT` afterwards 2. `TOP` is not deterministic without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Martin:No DB_AvailabilityFlag = 'Y' means i ll select top 1* and then i ll change that 'Y' as 'ASSIGNED' and insert values into other columns

Comment: Is the "No" an answer to this question "Are you saying that you should only do the insert if the update succeeds"? If so are the values of `@NEC_CustomerCode` and `@NEC_CustomerName` supposed to be derived from the row that gets updated? If not how is the `insert` at all related to the `update`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged with sql-server-2008 you could consider usinge the MERGE-statement:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `where` clause to make the insert conditional:

```
INSERT INTO NEC_Customer_DB_Map(NEC_CustomerCode,NEC_CustomerName) 
SELECT @NEC_CustomerCode,@NEC_CustomerName
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NEC_Customer_DB_Map where DB_AvailabilityFlag = 'Y')
```

Comment: This misses the Update part entirely.

Comment: i need 'Y' as 'ASSIGNED' and it is top 1*