# Insert into history table and selecting validFrom and validTo dates based on table contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Edit: Using SQL-Server 2008

I have an AccountHistory table that has multiple columns. Relevant for this case is Account_FK, ValidTo, ValidFrom

Im trying to insert new values into this table by using:

```
INSERT INTO AccountHistory (Account_FK, ValidTo, ValidFrom)
SELECT Account_FK, ValidTo, ValidFrom
FROM someOtherTable
```

Problem is:
If there is an existing row with the same Account_FK in AccountHistory, the inserted row should have its ValidFrom date set to current date. ValidTo should be null. And the old AccountHistory-row should have its ValidTo date updated from null to current date.
If there is no other row with the same Account_FK then the validFrom date should be set to a system-default start date, e.g. 1990-01-01

How is this most easily and elegantly solved? I know a trigger might be the thing, but if there is a better way then i would like to hear your suggestions.

ValidFrom field is a not null field so i cant insert any null into it.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server please? SQL Server 2008+ gives you MERGE http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: While a trigger seems nice, you'd be embedding business logic in it... what happens if the trigger fails?  I think a procedure with the embedded business logic to make the necessary updates where you can capture the errors and handle them more eloquently seems like a better choice.  Just my 2 cents

Comment: Sorry, Im using SQL Server 2008, just edited the question with this info!

Comment: Btw. I dont think the MERGE is a viable solution. Since the AccountHistory table might contain lots of rows with the Same Account_FK, only differed by validTo and ValidFrom dates. Matching might produce multiple results and i would need to pick the top date result of the matches, which dont think i can do with merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to remove the `ValidTo` field, which is effectively a **derived** field (which you're *usually* not supposed to store).  Then, you only have to insert the relevant entries, and can derive the needed value fairly trivially (requires aggregated self-join).

However, I'm a little concerned that you're overriding the given `ValidFrom` date if an entry exists - you're effectively making it impossible to back-date history, and that new entries will always be 'new, and currently in effect', which is extremely unlikely.  For one thing, if you ever insert multiple entries, you *may not* have a garuanteed insert order, which will promptly play havoc with this.  It also makes it impossible to back-date entries, if necessary (note: this isn't necessarily for nefarious purposes - there are occasionally good business reasons to backdate 'eligible' history.  Include an entry timestamp, for auditing, though).  Also, what happens when you have multiple entries for the same day - how would you know which one was correct (so are you sure you don't actually want a timestamp)?

Other than that, here's the two statements (tested on DB2) I would use to modify the table as you described.
First, an insert statement to take care of the new entries:

```
INSERT INTO AccountHistory (Account_FK, ValidTo, ValidFrom)
SELECT a.Account_FK, CASE WHEN b.Account_FK IS NULL 
                          THEN a.ValidTo
                          ELSE NULL END,
                     CASE WHEN b.Account_FK IS NULL
                          THEN a.ValidFrom
                          ELSE CURRENT_DATE END
FROM SomeOtherTable as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Account_FK
           FROM AccountHistory) as b
ON b.Account_FK = a.Account_FK
```

And an update statement to populate 'ValidTo' dates (this gets everything, not just what was inserted):

```
UPDATE AccountHistory as a SET ValidTo = (SELECT MIN(b.ValidFrom)
                                          FROM AccountHistory as b
                                          WHERE a.Account_FK = b.Account_FK
                                          AND b.ValidFrom > a.ValidFrom)
WHERE ValidTo IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
            FROM AccountHistory as b
            WHERE a.Account_FK = b.Account_FK
            AND b.ValidFrom > a.ValidFrom)
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your solution! This looks like it would work like a charm and i will take your suggestions and test them on our system. It is however a complicated process fit your solution into ours since i'm creating a dynamic query based on quite a few factors and the self-join could be a bit tricky to implement. But i'll look into it and post back soon :) As for your concern about overriding the given ValidFrom-date. I agree, but actually i do not have a given validFrom-date, i just wrote it for simplicities sake. And i agree about your other concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If using 2008 you can use the merge statement - [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server) - see Keith's answer about a third of the way down.  Would that work?

Comment: I dont think the MERGE is a viable solution. Since the AccountHistory table might contain lots of rows with the Same Account_FK, only differed by validTo and ValidFrom dates. Matching might produce multiple results and i would need to pick the top date result of the matches, which dont think i can do with merge?

Comment: yup that could be tricky reading your question again.  I just wondered if you could just use a single date column in your history table, saving you having to seek the previous record and update it - which like you said does sound to me like a natural job for a trigger.  (as long as I have read your question correctly!) Every new record will have a FromDate that matches the previous record's ToDate - so could fromDate be recorded alone with just inserts?  The ranges can still be extracted from this data.  Apologies if misunderstood!

Comment: Good point. That would solve a lot of headache. I'll check with our DBA if he would let me do that.