# Which one is more effective to do

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with large amount of data and want to take too much inquiry for checking the existence of a specific row. If that row exist then increase value of inquiry_count column. 
We have tow different approach to do this please tell me which one is better.

**first :**
we can select that row and check it with "Exists" function, If that row exists then Execute update command to increase inquiry_count column.

**Second:**
we can only execute update command. if the number of affected rows are more than 0 then that row exists.

Comment: In most cases I would expect `EXISTS` to be better, but Eugene is right in that you'd need to test it. Frankly the most important thing here is: "is there a suitable index to use for the check". And updating *data* as part of a *query* sounds.... odd.

Comment: I agree - code them both and test them yourself.  Remember to give consideration to how frequently the two possibilities occur *(no record found, and records-found then updated)*.

Comment: Bear in mind that check/update would be subject to changes in the underlying data, unless you apply some serious locking within a transaction. You might want to avoid that.

Comment: It would probably help to see your schema, along with the queries that you use in both scenarios. There may be room for further optimization there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems related to that post if you are concerned by performances issues:
[Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Write both queries, check both with SQL Profiler which one works better in your scenario.

Comment: regularly second scenario must be better, Because update command should find that row, if that row exist then apply update.

Answer (score 0):

I think both queries do not really fit.

1. EXISTS is only used for subqueries, where it is very performand. - But not used for standalone checks.
2. UPDATE should really only be used to update data, not for existence checks.

I would suggest to query with a TOP Query and use an appropriate index.

e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 {ID} FROM {TABLE} WHERE {YOUR CHECK HERE}
```

Comment: this query is better than "Exists".

Comment: 1) In my opinion, this is simply untrue. `IF EXISTS()` is a very standard construct. 2) If the 'normal' situation is that the update will be required, optimisitcally running the update and then checking for success/failure is also a normal construct. `IF (check) UPDATE` is more fit for cases where it is more normal for the record to *not* be found. Overall, I strongly disagree with this answer.