# How do I design my method's return type and stored procedure's return value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, t-sql

Let's take basic scenario where I want to insert a record during user registration only if no username exists in the database.

My question is will you create 2 separate stored procedures and make 2 calls to the database one for checking whether the username exists or not and 2nd one to actually insert into the database or will you create one stored procedure and write both the queries inside that only?

If you create one stored procedure, then my 2nd question what should you actually return from stored procedure? I normally return hard coded numbers from stored procedures and then check inside code. Is this a good practise?

Comment: *personally* I wouldn't even use a stored procedure... just saying...

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for your reply. However my next question would be, I am working with Micro ORM (PetaPoco) and it really stresses on use of inline SQL. I was thinking rather than writing inline SQL, shouldn't I go with stored procs? PetaPoco does have a way to call stored procs.

Comment: @MarcGravell, better be careful, or the holy war of SP vs. dynamic SQL is going to start again... ;)

Comment: @Lucero bring it on! (just, not here on SO)

Comment: @Marc: Please leave the war aside. Answer my question. Is inline SQL with PetaPoco/Dapper fine?

Comment: @Tom if that meets your local policy, then: absolutely; just invoke something like `insert [table]({cols}) select {values} where not exists (select 1 from [table] where SomeKey = @someKey) select @@rowcount`; simple and atomic. Could also use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in place of `@@ROWCOUNT` if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewUser
(
  @Username         VARCHAR(30)
, @Password         VARCHAR(30)
, @UserExists       BIT OUTPUT
)

AS

-- CHECK IF THE USER EXISTS:
DECLARE @RowCount INT

SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM Users
WHERE Username = @Username


IF (@RowCount > 0)
BEGIN
   SET @UserExists = 1
END
ELSE

BEGIN

   SET @UserExists = 0

   INSERT INTO Users
     (Username, [Password])
   VALUES
     (@Username, @Password)
END

GO
```

Then in the application you could use the @UserExists parameter, 1 would indicate that the user already exists, 0 would indicate that the user did not exist and has been created.

For good practice you should use stored procedures and not inline SQL as you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks you gave a nice example. Actually I am using PetaPoco and I don't think it is vulnerable to SQL injection because it uses parameterised queries.

Comment: Note, this sample is fundamentally broken. The `SELECT` alone will not lock the table, therefore it is possible that you get into a race if the SP runs in parallel with the same user name specified twice.

Comment: (Too late for an edit, therefore as an additional comment): Read for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server) to get more input, or google for "race condition sql insert" or so.

Comment: One more link which is a very good read: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx

Comment: @Lucero - the code I provided was not meant to be a definite solution and only a guide to how to approach the problem.  You could take the example further by adding locking hints to the query and wrapping the query in a transaction block if you wish to do so.

Comment: It's not a wish of mine, fact is that the given code is plain broken (but this isn't noticeable in single-user usage, which may trap the asking person into believing it is a viable solution). Many people use SO as knowledge base and this is exactly how broken code gets spread.

Comment: @Lucero - I have created a multi threaded test program to attempt to replicate what you say.  The program consists of two threads executing the stored procedure simultaneously (One thread executing the SP twice from the same connection, and another thread creating a new connection doing the same). 
Therefore, 2 connections executing the same SP twice. The output is: The row gets inserted (Thread 1), Row exists (Thread 1), Row exists (Thread 2), Row exists (Thread 2). I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and it seems to handle this fine, i.e. first come first serve basis.

Comment: @Lucero just for clarification.  I am not saying that a race condition is impossible in this context, from my tests I was unable to replicate one and therefore I think the issue is not as prudent as you may think. If you could provide test results where this has been replicated using my code I will gladly take a look, I will also share my test code with you also, if you wish.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, the time window which can cause problems is very small, so that you need to either run multiple threads in an infinite loop or then use a timed approach such as the one shown in [Dan's article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx) (linked to cached Google copy because the original site seems to be unaccessible right now). Race conditions usually do not manifest themselves before being in the wild, where concurrent access is much more likely (especially for web apps).

Answer (score 4):

This operation ultimately needs to be "atomic" - the check cannot be detached from the actual creation or you might run into concurrency issues. While you can handle some of it with transactions and locking accross two or more SPs, the best way IMHO is to use one SP and perform the check at the same time (in the same statement) as the insert occurs.

I'd return a recordset with the full record of the inserted user, and raise an error if there is a name conflict.

Comment: Hi Lucero, thanks for reply. I am wondering how should I then design my method? Should I have a generic class which holds the return value from stored procedure? and that generic class should have Enums. Eg. Insertion_Failed, User_Already_Exists and so on.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PetaPoco/Dapper since I use a different ORM, but the problem has nothing to do with the .NET side of things really. Just like when you do multithreading you have to think of possible concurrency issues, especially race conditions, when developing code that accesses the DB.

Answer (score 3):

I will do one stored procedure that will return the ID of the newly inserted user or -1 if no insert occured

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` statement may be helpful. Let say `MERGE` is conditional `INSERT`/`UPDATE`. In **single** statement you can `INSERT` new user if it does not exist or just `UPDATE` it if exists.

As written by other folks: stored procedure is much better then dynamic SQL. Wrap `MERGE` into `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

In real world, user interaction / workflow in your app / webapp will tell you if you need one or two procedures.

Scenario A)

- Give me your user data
- I will create an account for you or just update it (one stored procedure)

In scenario A do `MERGE` for conditional `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

Scenario B)

- Give me your user data and decide if you want to sing up or just login
- (You want to sign up) - Checking if given login is free (first stored procedure or just query)
- (It's free; Sign up!) - Creating an account, but have to check again if login is still free (second strored procedure)

In scenario B you may check for login existance and then do `INSERT` or (better) do `INSERT` in `TRY .. CATCH` block. You can do `RAISERROR` in `CATCH` block with useful message / state - so you can report problem with creating account by throwing "exception" from SQL (instead of return param) and catching it in your application code. This logic may be more useful in coding.