# How to GROUP BY in left join

Tags: sql-server, database

*

I'm getting results like below

`PID` is repeated here, 2 rows are displaying 1 patient (john)

I have to display only 1 row for patient_name (john)
i have to display one row for patient john if he have multiple visits on the same date or any other date..

Comment: 2 visits, 2 rows. Why should it be different? You have `from Patient_Master left join Patient_Visit`

Comment: i have to display only 1 row for multiple visits of patient

Comment: So you don't want to see every visit but only one(which,the last?) for each patient?

Comment: If you want to `count` the number of visits for a patient, then your question is right, otherwise your question is wrong itself since your output is okay, i guess.

Comment: @sarwar:i have to display one row for patient john if he have multiple visits on the same day or any other day...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Showing one row per patient - and his/her last visit date:

```
SELECT 
    Patient_Master.PID, 
    Patient_Master.Patient_ID,
    Patient_Master.Patient_Name,
    Patient_Master.Sex,
    Patient_Master.Patients_Birth_Date,
    Patient_Last_Visit.Visit_Date 
FROM 
    Patient_Master 
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT 
          PID,
          MAX(Visit_Date) AS Visit_Date
      FROM
          Patient_Visit
      GROUP BY
          PID 
    ) AS Patient_Last_Visit
        ON Patient_Master.PID = Patient_Last_Visit.PID 
ORDER BY 
    Patient_Master.Patient_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

@nikhil Could you be a little more specific?

If you want to have just one row for patient why are you joining tables?

I think you should do group on columns from Patient_Master and some aggregation on Patient_Visit

EDIT:
This should work

```
    SELECT 
        Patient_Master.PID, 
        Patient_Master.Patient_ID,
        Patient_Master.Patient_Name,
        Patient_Master.Sex,
        Patient_Master.Patients_Birth_Date
    FROM 
        Patient_Master 
    INNER JOIN
        Patient_Visit ON Patient_Master.PID = Patient_Visit.PID 
    GROUP BY
        Patient_Master.PID, 
        Patient_Master.Patient_ID,
        Patient_Master.Patient_Name,
        Patient_Master.Sex,
        Patient_Master.Patients_Birth_Date
    ORDER BY 
        Patient_Master.Patient_Name
```

This query selects information about patients with a least one visit.

Comment: :i have to display one row for patient john if he have multiple visits on the same date or any other date..

Answer (score 1):

use below query that will return single row..if all the values for rows are same

```
SELECT 
    Patient_Master.PID, 
    Patient_Master.Patient_ID,
    Patient_Master.Patient_Name,
    Patient_Master.Sex,
    Patient_Master.Patients_Birth_Date,
    Patient_Visit.Visit_Date 
FROM 
    Patient_Master 
LEFT JOIN
    Patient_Visit ON Patient_Master.PID = Patient_Visit.PID    
Group by 
    Patient_Master.PID, 
    Patient_Master.Patient_ID,
    Patient_Master.Patient_Name,
    Patient_Master.Sex,
    Patient_Master.Patients_Birth_Date,
    Patient_Visit.Visit_Date   
ORDER BY 
    Patient_Master.Patient_Name
```

Comment: Using Above query reopeated rows getting for one PID multiple visits

Comment: That's true , but you didnt select Visit_Trans_ID in your select query. so i think you dont care visit trans ids.  if your visit date is different then you can get 2 rows ...but in above query your visit date is same. so it make sense that single user visited on same day multiple times then have single row ..but if he visited on different days then have different rows.. my solution is worked if you alter visited date.

Comment: using Visit_Trans_ID what can i do..any ideas

Comment: if your visit date is different then you can get 2 rows ...but in above query your visit date is same. so it make sense that single user visited on same day multiple times then have single row ..but if he visited on different days then have different rows.. my solution is worked if you alter visited date

Comment: prakash i have to display one row for patient john if he have multiple visits on the same date or any other date..

Comment: ok..so for that u need to remove Patient_Visit.Visit_Date   from select and group by clause.

Comment: but i need Patient_Visit.Visit_Date to display visit of particular patient on particular date ....can i use "join (select distinct YOUR_COLUMNS_HERE ...)" like this

Answer (score 1):

I think this would give you single row, try this

```
SELECT 
        Patient_Master.PID, 
        Patient_Master.Patient_ID,
        Patient_Master.Patient_Name,
        Patient_Master.Sex,
        Patient_Master.Patients_Birth_Date,
        Patient_Visit.Visit_Date 
    FROM 
        Patient_Master 
    INNER JOIN
        Patient_Visit ON Patient_Master.PID = Patient_Visit.PID 
    GROUP BY Patient_Master.PID
    ORDER BY 
        Patient_Master.Patient_Name
```

Comment: Error :Column 'Patient_Master.Patient_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Show one patient per distinct date:

```
SELECT  M.PID, 
        M.Patient_ID,
        M.Patient_Name,
        M.Sex,
        M.Patients_Birth_Date,
        A.Visit_Date 
FROM    Patient_Master AS M 
        OUTER APPLY
        (
                SELECT  DISTINCT V.Visit_Date
                FROM    Patient_Visit AS V
                WHERE   V.PID = M.Pid
        ) AS A;
```

Show one patient and the most recent date:

```
SELECT  M.PID, 
        M.Patient_ID,
        M.Patient_Name,
        M.Sex,
        M.Patients_Birth_Date,
        A.Visit_Date 
FROM    Patient_Master AS M 
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  MAX(V.Visit_Date) AS Visit_Date
            FROM    Patient_Visit AS V
            WHERE   V.PID = M.Pid
        ) AS A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you need.  Maybe

```
GROUP BY PID, Patient_ID, Patient_Name, Sex,
         Patients_Birth_Date,MAX(Visit_Trans_ID),MAX(Visit_Date)
```

Comment: i have to display one row for patient john if he have multiple visits on the same date or any other date..