# What is the most efficient way to UPDATE existing rows and INSERT non-exist rows in a table-copy operation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
stock:

pid name qty
--- ---- ---
1   aaaa   2
2   bbbb   3
1   aaaa   5
3   cccc   1
2   bbbb   2

stock_total:

pid name total_qty
--- ---- ---------
```

I can insert rows from `stock` table with the total qty to `stock_total` using this query

```
INSERT INTO stock_total (pid, name, total_qty)
SELECT pid, name, SUM(qty) 
FROM stock
GROUP BY pid, name
```

The problem is, I will run the SQL above via cron job. So on the next execution, the SQL should UPDATE existing product and INSERT non-exist products.

It would be very inefficient if I loop over the SELECT results, check each row if exists in `stock_total` and do the INSERT or UPDATE.

Is there any simpler way for achieving this? perhaps by modifying the SQL above. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Comment: Which brand of SQL?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?  Different implementations have different options available to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and experimenting with the answers here, I came up with this solution. It turns out that MySQL supports `REPLACE INTO...` and `...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. So my query would be like this:

```
REPLACE INTO stock_total
SELECT pid, name, SUM(qty)
FROM stock
GROUP by pid, name
```

or,

```
INSERT INTO stock_total
SELECT pid, name, SUM(qty)
FROM stock
GROUP by pid, name
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_qty=VALUES(total_qty)
```

If a row exists on `stock_total`, the first query will DELETE then INSERT the new row,
and the second query will UPDATE the existing row.

Both query will only work if the table has a primary key or unique index:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_total (
    pid         INT         NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    total_qty   INT         NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE (pid, name)
);
```

Documentation:

- [REPLACE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)
- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(col1, col2)
VALUES (@value, ‘yyy’)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = @value
```

Answer (score 1):

This for the update:

```
UPDATE stock_total
SET total_qty = SUM(s.qty)
FROM stock_total st
INNER JOIN stock s
ON st.pid = s.pid
AND st.name = s.name
WHERE s.pid = st.pid
GROUP BY s.pid
```

And this for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO stock_total
SELECT s.pid, s.name, SUM(s.qty)
FROM stock s
WHERE s.pid NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM stock_total)
GROUP BY s.pid, s.name
```

Should be fine, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Majid, Im not familiar with this syntax I work with SQL Server, feel free to edit my post with your suggestions if it will improve the query or the answer.

Comment: The `UPDATE` doesn't work and the `INSERT` missed the `GROUP BY`. But I get your point. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the insert. What error do you get on the update?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you call a Stored Procedure from the job?

In the SP in the block catch the `DUPLICATE KEY` exception and `UPDATE`. If no `EXCEPTION` is thrown it will `INSERT`.

Comment: I'm a no-SP fans, but nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is what you are searching for. Use it as follows -

```
merge into stock_total s " +
                        "using (select ? pid, ? name, ? total_qty from dual) d " +
                        "on (s.pid = d.pid and s.name = d.name and s.total_qty = d.total_qty) " +
                        "when matched then " +
                        "update set s.pid= d.pid, s.name = d.name, s.total_qty = d.total_qty" +
                        "when not matched then " +
                        "insert (pid, name, total_qty) " + 
                        "values(d.pid, d.name, d.total_qty)" ;
```

**EDIT**(for mySQL):

```
MERGE INTO table_name WITH (HOLDLOCK) USING table_name ON (condition)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...])
```

Comment: I answered it according to OP's original question, he then added it to mysql tag. but this works for oracle very well. for mysql see my edit...

Comment: I think the end SQL would be very long and the `WITH (HOLDLOCK)` freaked me out :). But thanks.