# How to have error validation if value exist already in the database?

Tags: c#, database, insert

I have three textbox in the web form, which is username, password and IC number that the user have to enter to register. if the IC number the person entered, matches the IC value of any record in the database, it will update the username and password that the person have typed into the username field and password field of that record that have the matching IC. If the IC that the person entered, doesn;t matches the IC of any record in the database, it will not update any existing record and it will say IC does not exist in a label. Currently the lblErrorMessage.Text = "IC does not exist"; in the catch exception doesn't work.  It will just redirect to registered, even tho if the IC entered doesn't exist in the database. any help?

Comment: You don't, you use UPDATE. Everything else is about what you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`UPDATE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) not `INSERT`, `INSERT` is used for inserting new records. What you are currently doing is updating the existing record, not inserting it.

Like:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    string sql = @"UPDATE patient 
                   SET 
                    pUserName = @pUserName,
                    pPassword = @pPassword
                   WHERE pIC = @pIC";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtIC.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUsername", txtUsername.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", txtPassword.Value);

    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //rest of the code

}
```

Comment: @Jordjmax you can't use single query for either update or insert. Check if item exists and then use appropriate query

Comment: Thanks, it worked if i entered a nric number into the textbox that exist in the database. But if I entered a IC that doesn't exist in the database, it still go to Response.Redirect("registered.aspx"); but nothing is inserted into the database tho so it's good. I want it to display this lblErrorMessage.Text = "IC does not exist"; and not redirect to registered.aspx if the IC entered doesn't exist in database. Looks like it didn't work @Habib

Comment: @Jordjmax, as Sergey already explained, You need two different queries for that, You can either INSERT or UPDATE the table. You can query the database to see if you already have a record against your ID or you could write a procedure that would do `UPSERT` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873747/fast-upsert-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: ok saw that, and dun undestand. Erm, so what you have given me is the update codes, and it worked for me for checking if ic number is in database, if it is, then it will add the values inside username and password. and you are telling me for error validation if IC doesn't exist in database, i need a insert code?  @Habib

Comment: @Jordjmax, you need to first query your database , see if record exists, if it does then execute update query, if the record doesn't exist then execute INSERT query see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873747/fast-upsert-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: I updated my post above, I tried to write the code. The link u gave is not c#. I'm not sure how to write it, got few red lines. And i dun understand, I thought should be if record exists, then execute update query, then if record doesn't exist then show message saying IC doesn't exist? @Habib

Comment: @Jordjmax, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698683/961113

Comment: Ok saw that. But why do I need the insert query? I do not want to insert a new record. @Habib

Comment: @Jordjmax, I am not really sure what exactly you need, you need to do some study about SQL, Databases, and ADO.Net using C#. From your question and previous conversation it appears that you need to INSERT new record, if that doesn't exists in Table or UPDATE if it already exists. Do you even have a clue what INSERT and UPDATE means ?

Comment: I changed my explaination above, pls take a look thanks. @Habib

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
 SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2,...
 WHERE some_column = some_value;
```

To "insert" into existing record. You need to UPDATE it.

Comment: How about error validation for the IC?  @Noran

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` statement in place of `Insert`

Replace your `string sql` with this

```
string sql = "UPDATE patient SET pUsername=@pUsername, pPassword=@pPassword "+;
             "WHERE pIC=@PIC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C# but you should do something like this:

First, check the user input with the database;

```
("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE pIC = 'picinputVar'");
```

Then, check with an if statement if it returned any values. if it didn't print a massage saying the pIC doesn't exist.

if it did use UPDATE instead of INSERT

```
("UPDATE patient SET pUsername='usernameinput', pPassword='passwordinput' WHERE pIC='picinputVar'");
```

Comment: Thanks, i am left with the pIC doesn't exist error message on the label. the code i put at the catch exception doesn't work. how to write the if statement? put at catch exception also? @VeilSide