# multiple SqlConnections for one feature: bad idea?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I got an asp.net gridview connected to my sql database. When Inserting a new record or updating a record im doing some serverside checks and then either update/insert a record or do nothing. right now i got 2 methods CheckArtistExists and CheckSongExists which are both using a SqlConnection Object e.g.

```
public bool CheckSongExists(string _title, int _artistId)
    {
        int cnt = -1;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            //check if song already is exists in DB
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(ID) from tblSong WHERE Title = @newTitle AND ArtistId = @newArtistId;", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"newTitle", _title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"newArtistId", _artistId);
            con.Open();
            cnt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            // if cnt ==1 song exists in DB, of cnt == 0 song doesnt exist
            if(cnt == 1)
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
        }
    }
```

So for the Update function in the gridview i need to establish 3 SqlConnections (at max) one to check for the artist(if artist doesnt exist i have to insert a record to tblArtist first)
then a check if the song exists(only if artist exists) and finally if song doesnt exist I have to insert a new record.

I know database connections are valuable resources thats why i put them in a using block. So im not quite sure if its good style to use 3 SqlConnection objects to update/insert. Can you please tell me if my code is ok or if i should rather use another approach for this problem.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET internally manages the underlying Connections to the DBMS in the [ADO-NET Connection-Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx):

> In practice, most applications use only one or a few different
>   configurations for connections. This means that during application
>   execution, many identical connections will be repeatedly opened and
>   closed. To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an
>   optimization technique called connection pooling.
>
> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical
>   connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active
>   connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user
>   calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it
>   returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the
>   application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to
>   the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the
>   connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.

So obviously there's no reason to avoid creating,opening or closing connections since actually they aren't created, opened and closed at all. This is "only" a flag for the connection pool to know when a connection can be reused or not. But it's a very important flag, because if a connection is "in use"(the connection pool assumes), a new physical connection must be openend to the DBMS what is very expensive.

So you're gaining no performance improvement if you "reuse" connections but the opposite.

- Create, open(in case of Connections), use, close and dispose them where you need them(f.e. in a method)
- use the [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose and close(in case of Connections) implicitely

So yes, it's absolutely fine to use one connection per method since you are not using a physical connection at all if connection-pooling is enabled (default).

Another question is if you could improve your approach. You could create a stored-procedure which checks existence and updates or inserts accordingly.

[Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)