# Update if exits or Insert if not

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am coding an application which will insert if the primary key isn't found or update if it is found. 
Its the same type of situation that is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server) on this site.

Question.

Right now i am using the following  code for a insert. (Names have been changed but same format)

```
 Using con As New SqlConnection
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                Try
                    con.ConnectionString = "removed"
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table] ([primary key],[value]) VALUES (@primary key, @value)"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primary key", code to grab key)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", code for value)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

The complete code above works for me. 
But now i need it to only do inserts of the primary key isn't found.

Based on the above link, is the answer to do something like this

```
  cmd.CommandText = "Merge Table as target using (values ('key') as source(key) on taget.idfield = code for key...
```

This doesn't feel right to me, (possibly because its all on one line). Whats the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Whats wrong with writing a `select`, then an `update` or `insert` depending on if it exists?

Comment: That was my first idea, but i wanted to make sure that was the right way to go about doing it.

Comment: I think you'll find that a `Merge` while neat, is harder to maintain over time.  KIS - Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Merge` is definitely a great way of accomplishing this task.  Your code should look something similar to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = 
@"
    Merge into Table as Target 
    Using (Select @PrimaryKey As PrimaryKey) As Source
        On Target.PrimaryKey = Source.PrimaryKey
    When not matched then
        Insert (PrimaryKey, Value)
        Values (@PrimaryKey, @Value)
    When matched then 
        Update 
        Set Value = @Value
    ;
";
```

Answer (score 1):

select and insert/update requires 2 trips to the database.

So here is just one:

```
MERGE INTO yourTable target
USING (select val1 as key1, val2 as key2... from dual) source
ON (target.primary_key = source.key1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.column2 = source.key2....
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (target.primary_key, target.column2, ...)
VALUES(source.key1, source.key2, ...)
```

I am converting your incoming parameters into dataset using oracle syntax,
on other databases it will be different (SQL Server, for example: 'select val1 as key1, ...')

Comment: You don't have to make seperate trips to the database, I can do this all in one in SQL. Also he tagged Sql not Oracle...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, sql does not mean sql server.  Granted, it is LIKELY, having also tagged vb.net, that its sql server.  But not guaranteed.