# Update if a key, or combination of keys, exists, otherwise INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL insert in SQL-Server that looks like this:

```
  INSERT INTO Configuration.Localization ( languageid, localizationkey, localizationvalue)  VALUES
(lang,'core.common.altered','(altered)'),
(lang,'core.common.cancel','Cancel'),
(lang,'core.common.ordernumber','Order number'),
(lang,'core.common.prefix','Prefix') ...
```

and so on.

How do I modify this query to use `UPDATE` instead of insert (similarly to "`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`" in MySQL), while keeping the overall structure of the query (I want it still to be one operator, not many).

Preferably I would like to be specific in the query, that `UPDATE` must happen if `lang` and `localizationkey` both match.

Comment: did you try using merge http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: I'd use the [solution by Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server/21209295#21209295)

Comment: I was about to post on the question when it was closed.  http://craftydba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/move-to-history.sql_.txt has code for an UPSERT.  It happens to fall into on of the cases Aaron mentions.