# Update table to insert new row if it does not exist

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, sql-insert

```
id | Product    | PrdouctOption| ServiceId
1  | 1          | 1            | 12
2  | 2          | 1            | 12
3  | 1          | 1            | 13
4  | 2          | 1            | 13
5  | 1          | 2            | 14
6  | 1          | 1            | 15
```

How do I **update all records** in my table to insert a new row of **product = 2** and **productOption = 1** if it does not exist for a **ServiceId**. *(in this case for serviceId 14 and 15)*

I cannot seem to get a logic right.

So far this is what I have..

```
  UPDATE dbo.MyTable
  SET Product = 2, ProductOption = 1

//Can't figure out the logic for if it doesn't exist for a serviceid
```

Comment: You want to perform an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` or maybe both?

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: And which DBMS are you using? Either mysql or sql-server, they are not the same thing.

Comment: I think you want to insert a new record for existing service id's that don't have a product 2 product option 1... is that right?

Comment: Sorry, It would be Insert in to my table if it does not exist

Comment: @xQbert Yes that is correct

Comment: Looks like `sql-server`not `mysql`. please check your tags.

Comment: @SeanLange sql-server using MSSMS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional insert could look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Product,ProductOption, ServiceId)
SELECT DISTINCT 2,1, serviceId FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table1
   WHERE product = 2
   AND ProductOption = 1
   AND ServiceId = t1.ServiceId)
```

Comment: This partially works.. it does not give the ServiceId to the new row.

Comment: Ah, now I finally get what you're trying to do. Please review my revised answer.

Comment: That has created duplications. It has inserted new rows for the ones that already exist.

Comment: I don't understand. The distinct keyword prevents that more than 1 insert is done for a serviceID. What duplicates do you mean?

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't mention ServiceId was a linked table. Had to tweak it a little bit but they above works :)

Answer (score 0):

An `UPDATE` statement affects rows that already exist in the table.

To add a new row to a table, you'd use an `INSERT` statement.

(Note that the `UPDATE` statement in the question will update *every* row in the table; there isn't any WHERE clause.)