# Perform sql server insert but if duplicate found then perform update

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc

I have many records and I want to fire a batch insert query in `MYSQL` and `MSSQL` using `JDBC`:

My query is : `INSERT INTO dentalitems SET itemID = ?, categoryid = ?, treatmentAreaID = ?, paintTypeID=?, procedurecode=?  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE itemID = ?, procedurecode = ?`

The query above is working fine for `MYSQL` - it will  insert the record into the table but if there is a duplicate key then it will perform an update.

My problem is that I want to perform the same above operation in SQL Server also but the query above is only for `MYSQL`. I searched for an SQL Server query but I did not find any.

In my table `itemID`  and `procedurecode` are unique columns.

How can I do the same thing with MSSQL Server?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server

Comment: `MERGE` is the keyword you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Table Location (LocationId INT PrimaryKey, LocationName VARCHAR)

```
MERGE dbo.Location AS target
USING (SELECT 100, 'Location Name') AS source (Id, Name)
    ON (target.LocationId = source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET LocationName = source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (LocationId, LocationName) VALUES (source.Id, source.Name);
```

->

```
MERGE dbo.Location AS target
USING (SELECT AId, AName FROM A) AS source (Id, Name)
    ON (target.LocationId = source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET LocationName = source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (LocationId, LocationName) VALUES (source.Id, source.Name);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. So, where does data come from for inserting or updating?

Comment: I have static data and I want to insert all the record into table but if table has particular record then I want to update it. I don't want to perform any selection in between