# Perform insert and update operation in one procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table Country in database with the following fields

- CountryId
- CountryName

Now I have to write a procedure which will first check whether @CountryName exists or not. If it already exists it should update that row. If it doesn't exists it should perform insert operation...

Comment: doublicate to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

I think below script will help you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName
@CountryName nvarchar(100),
@CountryID int

AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Country WHERE CountryName = @CountryName)
BEGIN
    --UPDATE
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    --INSERT
END

END
```

You can also do above code with merge keyword of SQL 
find reference  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/243670/4988990)

Answer (score 2):

```
Create Proc [ProcedureName]
@CountryName nvarchar(100)
As
Begin
Declare @Count int
Set @Count = (Select count(CountryId) from Country where CountryName = @CountryName)
if @Count > 0
Begin
-- update 
End
else
begin
-- insert
end

End
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is SQL Server 2005(or higher) version you are using, consider using the `MERGE`statement.
[Documentation for MERGE here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb510625.aspx)

```
merge [country] as target
using (select @CountryID, @CountryName) as source(id, name)
on (target.Countryid = source.id)
when matched then
    update set CountryName = @CountryName
when not matched then
    insert (CountryId, CountryName) values (source.id, source.name);
```

Comment: I know! This is just another approach.

Comment: yeh I know,my comment is for future users