# List of Objects bulk insert/Update in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

In a C# program,I have a list, which contains 5 objects

obj 1:

```
BaseId=105,ID=1,value=4,numberOfMembers=2
```

obj 2:

```
BaseId=105,ID=2,value=6,numberOfMembers=3
```

obj 3:

```
BaseId=105,ID=3,value=10,numberOfMembers=5
```

obj 4:

```
BaseId=105,ID=0,value=20,numberOfMembers=10
```

obj 5:

```
BaseId=105,ID=0,value=25,numberOfMembers=50
```

I need to insert/update all these together into an sql table on a single button click. When id=0 insert it and when id != 0,update the table.

The numberOfMembers is selected from a drop down[2,3,5,10]. For a BaseID, numberOfMembers do not repeat, avoid inserting data at that time.

Please help me to achieve it using a SQL query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *For a BaseID, numberOfMembers do not repeat, avoid inserting data at that time* - please elaborate this requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Comment: Dropdown values [2,3,5,10,50] is taken from another table. For one baseiD only 5 records are allowed. Do not select any of the drop down values more than one time

Comment: Use `Table_Value_Parameters` With `MERGE` Statement in Sql-Server.

Comment: Thanks to all your Replies. Merge statement helped me