# How to combine two SQLite statements running in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have these two statements:

```
db2.Execute(" UPDATE CLICKHISTORY SET " +
            " DAYOFYEAR = " + dayOfYear + " , " +
            " YEAR = " + year + " , " +
            " MONTH = " + month + " , " +
            " DAY = " + day + " , " +
            " BTNACOUNT = BTNACOUNT + 1 WHERE YYMMDD = " + yymmdd );
db2.Execute(" INSERT INTO CLICKHISTORY " +
            " (YYMMDD,DAYOFYEAR,YEAR,MONTH,DAY,BTNACOUNT) " +
            " VALUES ( " +
              yymmdd + " , " +
            dayOfYear + " , " +
            year + " , " +
            month + " , " +
            day + " , " +
            "1) WHERE changes() = 0");
```

What I would like to do is to check if changes() = 0 in the first statement before running the second statement.

Can anyone tell me how I can group together these two statements in to one so I can check the value of changes()?

Comment: The first statement will update all rows in the table. The second one is not valid SQL.

Comment: I have updated the second one and will refine and check more.  What I was showing was just an example.  What I need to do is to insert a row if it's not already there and update if it is.  I researched this and the most easy way would appear to be an update followed by an insert if the update didn't work

Comment: You could do `case count(select ...) when 0 then insert else update`, although this is plus additional query. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: In fact I guess this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/108403/728795

Comment: @Andrei SQLite works differently.

Comment: Every SQL driver should have some method to return the number of updated rows (but I don't know which one you're using).

Comment: Hey Alan! Can you post the code of your model? I.e. what does `CLICKHISTORY` look like, either as a POCO or a SQL Table.

Comment: How are you connecting to the DB? Can you post your connection code and which library you used? `Mono.Data.SQLite`?

Comment: What type is `db2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `db2` is of type `SQLite.SQLiteConnection`, you can use the return value of the `Execute` method to find out the number of affected rows - something like:

```
int rowsAffected = db2.Execute("UPDATE...");
if (rowsAffected == 0) {
    rowsAffected = db2.Execute("INSERT...");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In general, you can combine sqlite statements using semicolon `;`.

But as I understand, the real question here is: *How to conditionally insert values in SQLite?*

You cannot use `WHERE` with `INSERT INTO table VALUES(...)`, but use can use `INSERT INTO table SELECT ...` syntax instead and add a `WHERE` clause to select.

#### Example

Let's say I have a simple table: `scores (name varchar(20), score int)`. I want to update a row or insert a new one if there's nothing to update yet.

```
var name = "my team";
var sql  = $"update scores set score = score+1 where name = '{name}';" 
         + $"insert into scores(name, score) select '{name}', 0 where changes() = 0" ;

var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Depending on the driver you use, the C# methods used may differ - I'm using System.Data.Sqlite here.

You may also want to taka look at how to do [Upsert in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Can you explain the usage of the $" and also the paren around name?

Comment: @Alan2 The $"" and parentheses are the usage of the [C# string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). It's giving the same results as [string.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) but in a (IMO) more human-readable way.