# SQL IF exist date by day do increment update else insert data

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

How can I express the below statement as a SQL query ?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM expense_history 
           WHERE user_id = 40 
             AND DATE_FORMAT(expense_history.created_date , '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-06-02' 
             AND camp_id='80') 
    UPDATE expense_history  
    SET clicks = clicks + 1, 
        amount = amount + 1 
    WHERE user_id = 40 
      AND DATE_FORMAT(expense_history.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-06-02' 
      AND camp_id = '80'
ELSE
   INSERT INTO expense_history (camp_id, created_date, amount, user_id) 
   VALUES ('80', '2018-06-02 12:12:12', '1', '40')
END IF;
```

I just want to do increment clicks and amount if is set by day, else I want to add new row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Comment: search for UPSERT

Comment: Is this on MySQL?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL - Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I presumed your database is *mysql*, because of *DATE_FORMAT()* function(and edited your question as to be).

So, by using such a mechanism below, you can do what you want,

provided that a *COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY* for *camp_id, amount, user_id* columns :

```
SET @camp_id = 80,
    @amount  =  1,
    @user_id = 40,
    @created_date = sysdate();

INSERT INTO expense_history(camp_id,created_date,amount,user_id,clicks)
VALUES(@camp_id,@created_date,@amount,@user_id,ifnull(clicks,1))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    amount = @amount + 1,
    clicks = ifnull(clicks,0)+1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62c6eb/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky in MySQL.  You are storing a `datetime` but you want the date part to be unique.

Starting in MySQL 5.7.?, you can use computed columns for the unique constraint.  Here is an example:

```
create table expense_history (
  user_id int,
  camp_id int,
  amount int default 0,
  clicks int default 1,
  . . .
  created_datetime datetime,  -- note I changed the name
  created_date date generated always as (date(created_datetime)),
  unique (user_id, camp_id, created_datetime)
);
```

You can then do the work as:

```
INSERT INTO expense_history (camp_id, created_datetime, amount, user_id) 
    VALUES (80, '2018-06-02 12:12:12', 1, 40)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        amount = COALESCE(amount + 1, 1),
        clicks = COALESCE(clicks + 1, 1);
```

Earlier versions of MySQL don't support generated columns.  Nor do they support functions on `unique`.  But you can use a trick on a prefix index on a varchar to do what you want:

```
create table expense_history (
  user_id int,
  camp_id int,
  amount int default 0,
  clicks int default 1,
  . . .
  created_datetime varchar(19), 
  unique (created_datetime(10))
);
```

This has the same effect.

Another alternative is to store the date and the time in separate columns.