# Best Solution for checking DB before inserting / updating or deleting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Would like to know what would be the best way to check if the records exist before  INSERT/UPDATE or DELETE the record.

I assume MERGE would be an optimal way but i have read that i might not be the best solution as they have bugs and also affect performance (Now these articles that i have read could be older issues)

We are using SQL SERVER 2016. So any content relevant to this edition could be helpful?

I also think, checking the database based on the PK and based on the value returned that i can either perform an insert or update

for example
If ( count from the table is 0) then Insert else update.

I am just trying to find the best way to handle our daily transactions. Our application processes an average of 200,000 records/hour.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Comment: Could you clarify _I assume MERGE would be an optimal way but i have read that i might not be the best solution as they have bugs and also affect performance_

Comment: I assume for my scenario the best way is to use a  MERGE statement but then i have read about MERGE having issues and also could cause a performance impact. so i am asking for solutions

Comment: It is a possible duplicate .. Thanks for pointing out. But I think the confusion still exists as to which one would be better. Just looking for some real experiences.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored procedure that checks for the existence of the record before insertion, such as (assuming you have automatically generated identities for the primary key)

CREATE PROC PR_Insert_Something 
@FirstName
@LastName
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE A (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES(@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)
COMMIT TRAN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
RAISERROR() <-- Look up RAISERROR if unsure what to do here
ROLLBACK TRAN
END
END 
GO;

Always better to preform SQL operations dynamically from the application anyways.

Comment: Yeah,I was thinking the same. we might have to reconsider our design