# How to insert an entry with an incremented value if the Table is empty [SQL]

Tags: sql, null, insert, sql-insert

i do have a `Table: Example` with an entry, that looks as the following:

```
Example

entryID: 0, number:1;
```

if you were to insert a new entry, with entryID, incremented, you would do something like:

```
INSERT INTO "Example" VALUES(SELECT MAX(entryID)+1 FROM "Example"), 2);
```

**Question**: What if the `Example-Table` is empty? How do you add logic to your sql to check, If there aren't any than add entryID = 0?

Comment: As I have learned here in SO, in the most used database systems exits if else conditional options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

First, this code does not work in any database:

```
INSERT INTO "Example"
     VALUES (SELECT MAX(entryID)+1 FROM "Example"), 2);
```

It is missing the parentheses around the subquery.  This is more naturally written as `INSERT . . . SELECT`, rather than `INSERT . . . VALUES`.  The narrow answer to your question is `COALESCE()`:

```
INSERT INTO "Example" (EntryId, Number)
     SELECT COALESCE(MAX(entryID) + 1, 1), 2
     FROM "Example";
```

Note the column list in the `INSERT`.  It is a best practice to always include those.

This is the *narrow* answer, because this is not the right way to have an incrementing id.  You don't specify your database, but basically most databases have a syntax for incremental ids -- usually using syntax such as `identity`, `auto_increment`, `serial`, or `generated always as`.  This is the right way to add an incremental id.

Why is it the right way?  Your method can result in duplicates in a multi-threaded environment, where two inserts are made at the same time.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer and contribution. Also about auto_increment, how to set it up,so that it increments automatically ? What would be the Syntax for adding an Entry then? Everything that you mentioned `-EntryId ` ?

Comment: @Roman . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  I think you should ask a *new* question with a clear explanation and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: @Roman There is an option called autoincrement. Search here in SO or Internet for that.