# How to optimize visit counter SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, sql-update, query-optimization

Using SQL server 2016 I have created the table **VISIT** with 3 columns **ID**,**settoday**,**counter**. This is the **asp** code that I use to count the daily visits. There are more than 2000 records in this table so far:

```
<%
'today is calculated on local calendar then:

sql="select * from visit where settoday='"& today &"'"
recordSet.open sql,objcon
if not recordSet.eof then

    sql="update visit set counter=counter+1 where id=" & recordSet("id")
    objcon.execute sql

else
    
    sql="insert into visit (settoday,counter) values ('" & today & "','1')"
    objcon.execute sql

end if
recordSet.close
%>
```

The ID column is primary key and also I have created an Index on **settoday** column. But When I check the Event profiler, The update query is taking a long time to execute. What more can I do to optimize the update code?

Comment: Warning, your code is open to injection attacks. **Parametrise** your queries.

Comment: Do you have an index or primary key on the table

Comment: Yes I mentioned than ID is primary key and settoday is Indexed. @Charlieface

Comment: Please share the query plans for these queries via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: Why you need the index on the `settoday` column ? This can slow down any update on the table

Comment: are the statistics up to date? RDBMS believing the table is nearly empty sometimes ignore alll indexes

Comment: and have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server , I presume you want an update if exists

Comment: I have created Index on settoday for the first select query among 2000 records. Doen't help? @GuidoG

Comment: Always think before you create an index. The can help performance when searching, but they can slow down update and insert statements. In the code you have shown I dont think you need that index. But I don't know what other code you have off course

Comment: Thank you. There is no update on `settoday` column. It is just inserted once a day. Does it still slows down the update on `counter` column?@GuidoG

Answer (score 1):

I think you can gain a lot by avoiding having to go to the database twice.
Also you should always try to use placeholders and parameters rather than concatenate values etc. I think it's not that big of a problem here because I presume `today` is not a user-furnished value, but still.

2000 records isn't much at all but yes, having the index on `settoday` **will** help, especially as the table grows. If your current version is slow then I suspect the network overhead is more to blame than the actual execution of the queries.

Rather than first get the `ID` for `today` and then deciding on whether you need to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in asp you can do this in 1 single operation in SQL.
It's been ages since I did this kind of code and I had to write it up in notepad so you'll probably have to fix some things here and there, but I think it's a start:

```
<%
sql = "DECLARE @today datetime = ?

UPDATE counter
   SET counter = counter + 1
 WHERE settoday = @today
 
 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO visit (settoday, counter) values (@today, 1)"
    END"
    

set command = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")
set command.ActiveConnection = ...
command.QueryText = sql
command.CommandType = adCmdText
command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter("@p1", adDate, adParamInput, today))
command.Execute

%>
```