# How to make a method idempotent?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Here is a Rest Api method that sets the user rating. The database table contains the composite primary key: `user_id` +  `rate_id`.

When user tries to set the same rating the framework throws an exception. I catch it and return response.

How to handle such these cases and make the method idempotent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use firstOrCreate() or updateOrCreate() methods of laravel query builder to prevent this exception and keep your method idempotent

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail (and a code sample), it's difficult to advise.  However, in high-level, general terms you could do one of the following (presuming you are using a relational database):

- catch the Exception thrown by your database: if it relates to a duplicate primary key then you could handle the case accordingly (ie perhaps ignore it and continue as if the INSERT operation had succeeded)
- perform a `SELECT` operation on your database, just before you attempt to save the value.  If there is already a value there, then use `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`
- some databases (eg MySQL) have extensions to standard SQL that allow you to do things like `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT IGNORE`: you could use one of these instead of the standard `INSERT` statement

Comment: Thank you, from docs the POST method not idempotent. Therefore should I do this idempotent? Why just not return a exception message for the user?

Comment: here you have an answer which implement @Rob Eyre solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server