# How to use DbContext asynchronously

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a very long running operation that could be split into many shorter ones - if I was able to call `DbContext`asynchronously.

First of all, a data service:

```cs
public class MyDataService : IMyDataService
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _arepository;
    private readonly ITransactionScope _txScope;

    public MyDataService(IMyRepository repository, ITransactionScope txScope)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _txScope = txScope;
    }

    public async Task<Result> CreateOrAppendAsync(SomeObject[] someObjects)
    {
        return await _txScope.DoInTransactionAsync(
            _principal.GetName(),
            "create-or-append",
            null,
            async () => await _repository.CreateOrAppendAsync(someObjects));
    }
}
```

And then the repository:

```cs
public class MyRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly InternalDbContext _dbContext;

    public Repository(InternalDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Result> CreateOrAppendAsync(SomeObject[] someObjects)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<PartOfResult>>();
        foreach (var batch in someObjects.Split(10))
        {

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // do something with _dbContext to get result
            }));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
        return results.Combine();
    }
}
```

This of course does not work because of:

> A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

The question is: How would I do this correctly? Previously I've just copied the `DbContext`, but since all of this is part of the same transaction, that is not possible. The Postgres database should be able to handle multiple calls, Dotnet has such nice keywords to make parallel processing easy, but how does EF Core work together with all of this.

Comment: `DbContext` is a unit-of-work  and it should always be short-lived (i.e. not live longer than absolutely necessary, e.g. in ASP.NET it should be request-scoped; or in a more traditional batch-process it should be (akin to being) scoped to a single method and not stored in a field.

Comment: Where is `DoInTransactionAsync` defined? Are you certain you're using a "_real_" SQL `TRANSACTION` here - or just EF's _ersatz_ transactions? (fun-fact: it's easy to mess-up your DB with EF transactions unless you're very, very careful with how all of your rollbacks work, also consider your transaction-isolation level too).

Comment: Use two `DbContext` and than wrap the two call in a `TransactionScope` with `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` might work.

Comment: @Dai My bad, I didn't see that the transaction was some third-party class. But it uses the transaction off the `DbContext`. Sooo ersatz transaction? Can I use database transaction directly?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run queries not *asynchronously*, but *concurrently*. These are completely different things. If you want to run it asynchronously you just remove the `Task.Run`-part

```
public async Task<Result> CreateOrAppendAsync(SomeObject[] someObjects)
{
      var tasks = new List<Task<PartOfResult>>();
      foreach (var batch in someObjects.Split(10))
      {
          await CreateOrAppendAsync(batch);
      }
}
```

The point here is that the thread should not block while you are doing database operations.

If you want to run queries *concurrently* you need to create multiple dbContext objects, there is just no getting around this. Running concurrent queries might or might not improve anything, depending on the database and the queries.

Comment: The question is: when I have multiple dbContext objects, how do I handle a transaction between them?

Comment: @StefanS. Have a transaction for each and then you could manually rollback when one of them fails.

Comment: @StefanS. I'm no database expert, but I'm fairly sure you don't, and that transactions are inherently serial things. But you need to ask yourself what the real purpose is, ensuring UI is responsive? Then async is the way to go. Total runtime? This has more to do with database and query design. I would not expect batching to improve overall performance, since the db can already use concurrency internally.

Comment: @JonasH It's the total runtime. For each `SomeObject`, there is a big SELECT to question whether the object should be INSERTed or UPDATEd. And then to build the entity in EF core, there are multiple calls to the database necessary. I imagine all the reading of the database could be done in parallel, just the final inserting / updating has to be done one after the other.

Comment: @StefanS. The total amount of work will not change just because you are doing things in parallel. You might mean total *latency*. Regardless, you might want consider writing manual SQL for performance sensitive parts. EF is convenient, but does not always produce great SQL. That is likely better than trying to shoehorn in concurrency where it does not fit. Insert or Update should be possible to do with a single query, see [INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)