# How do I UPDATE a row in a table or INSERT it if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, postgresql, upsert

I have the following table of counters:

```
CREATE TABLE cache (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    generation int
);
```

I would like to increment one of the counters, or set it to zero if the corresponding row doesn't exist yet. Is there a way to do this without concurrency issues in standard SQL? The operation is sometimes part of a transaction, sometimes separate.

The SQL must run unmodified on SQLite, PostgreSQL and MySQL, if possible.

A search yielded several ideas which either suffer from concurrency issues, or are specific to a database:

- Try to `INSERT` a new row, and `UPDATE` if there was an error. Unfortunately, the error on `INSERT` aborts the current transaction.
- `UPDATE` the row, and if no rows were modified, `INSERT` a new row.
- MySQL has an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

EDIT: Thanks for all the great replies. It looks like Paul is right, and there's not a single, portable way of doing this. That's quite surprising to me, as it sounds like a very basic operation.

Comment: You're not going to find a single solution that works for all these RDBMS.  Sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite - UPSERT \*not\* INSERT or REPLACE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

MySQL (and subsequently SQLite) also support the REPLACE INTO syntax:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (pk_id, col1) VALUES (5, '123');
```

This automatically identifies the primary key and finds a matching row to update, inserting a new one if none is found.

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Actually, to be specific, MySQL's REPLACE always does an insert, but it will delete the row if it already exists, first. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replace.html

Comment: It is important to understand that it is an insert+delete and never and update.  The consequence of this, is that you will always want to make sure when you do a replace, you should always include data for all the fields.

Comment: @Zoredache Technically, it's a 'delete, then insert', as a(n) 'insert + delete' is effectively the same as a delete but that's splitting hairs.

Comment: @Agihammerthief there is a very real difference namely that the newly inserted row will NOT have the same primary key as the row that has been deleted. With ON DUPLICATE it will be the same primary key (unless you specifically change it).

Answer (score 33):

SQLite supports [replacing a row](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) if it already exists:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO [...blah...]
```

You can shorten this to

```
REPLACE INTO [...blah...]
```

This shortcut was added to be compatible with the MySQL `REPLACE INTO` expression.

Comment: It requires that you defined a `PRAMARY KEY` in your values.

Answer (score 30):

I would do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO cache VALUES (key, generation)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (key = key, generation = generation + 1);
```

Setting the generation value to 0 in code or in the sql but the using the ON DUP... to increment the value.  I think that's the syntax anyway.

Comment: This answer should honestly be the selected answer. It's a non-destructive edit if you aren't submitting all fields to an entry.

Answer (score 11):

the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause is the best solution because:
REPLACE does a DELETE followed by an INSERT so for an ever so slight period the record is removed creating the ever so slight possibility that a query could come back having skipped that if the page was viewed during the REPLACE query.

I prefer INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ... for that reason.

jmoz's solution is the best:
though I prefer the SET syntax to the parentheses

```
INSERT INTO cache 
SET key = 'key', generation = 'generation'
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE key = 'key', generation = (generation + 1)
;
```

Comment: REPLACE is atomic, so there's no period where the row doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know that you are going to find a platform-neutral solution.

This is commonly called an "UPSERT".

See some related discussions:

- [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)
- [SQL Server 2005 implementation of MySQL REPLACE INTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234)

Comment: Is that solution really applicable? and portable?

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL there is no merge command, and actually writing it is not trivial - there are actually strange edge cases that make the task "interesting".

The best (as in: working in the most possible conditions) approach, is to use function - such as one shown in [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) (merge_db).

If you don't want to use function, you can *usually* get away with:

```
updated = db.execute(UPDATE ... RETURNING 1)
if (!updated)
  db.execute(INSERT...)
```

Just remember that it is not fault proof and it **will** fail eventually.

Answer (score 4):

Standard SQL provides the MERGE statement for this task.  Not all DBMS support the MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a common way to atomically update or insert (e.g., via a transaction) then you can fallback to another locking scheme.  A 0-byte file, system mutex, named pipe, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an insert trigger? If it fails, do an update.

Comment: Trigger (at least in PostgreSQL) is running when the command worked. i.e. you can't have trigger that runs when base command failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using a library that writes the SQL for you, then you can use [Upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert) (currently Ruby and Python only):

```
Pet.upsert({:name => 'Jerry'}, :breed => 'beagle')
Pet.upsert({:name => 'Jerry'}, :color => 'brown')
```

That works across MySQL, Postgres, and SQLite3.

It writes a stored procedure or user-defined function (UDF) in MySQL and Postgres. It uses `INSERT OR REPLACE` in SQLite3.