# How to avoid inserting duplicate's into SQLite data base?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting contact information from server when i login through account. i am storing those information in SQLite, when user login second time, I don't want to same duplicate contact inserting again into SQLite.

i tried like this but not working

```
boolean exist= contact_db.CheckItem(entry.getUser());               
if(!exist) {
 // insert
}else {
 // don't insert
}
```

code in DB class

```
Cursor mCursor = database.query(ContactsDB.TABLE_CONTACTS, allColumns,
                    ContactsDB.CONTACT_USERID + "= ' " + name +"'" , null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) 
        return false;
    else return true;
```

How to avoid the duplicates while inserting the contacts into data base?

Comment: check the data before inserting.

Comment: you can check before inserting take all the contents of table in to arraylist and iterate it,compare to the contact to be inserting ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better would be to create a `UNIQUE` index for that column using [`UNIQUE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) Keyword. An example can be found [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573596/726863) and also a simpler one can be found [`here`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp).

After creating table you have to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` for row as,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_something ON Table_name 
                                          (column_name_1, column_name_2,....);
```

Comment: I am using like this but no change still it's creating new row in DB. "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "+ NEWS_TYPE +" ON " +TABLE_NEWS 
   + TABLE_NEWS + "(" + NEWS_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
   + NEWS_TYPE + " text ," 
   + NEWS_NAME + " text not null UNIQUE," 
   + NEWS_URL + " text " + "); ";

Answer (score 2):

Check the database for the information.
If the data is present in the database don't do anything if not insert the information into the database