# Correct usage of the SQLite ON CONFLICT clause

Tags: sqlite, insert-update, upsert

I have a SQLite database which, amongst other things, has the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS biases
(
 data INTEGER NOT NULL,
 link INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 bias_type INTEGER,
 ignores INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 desists INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 encashes INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
 accesses INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 scraps INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 CONSTRAINT pk_bias_mix PRIMARY KEY(data,link,bias_type)
);
```

The constraint `pk_bias_mix` is being used to ensure that no two rows can have the same values for all three columns `data`, `link` and `bias_type` columns.  So suppose I do

```
INSERT INTO biases (data,link,bias_type,ignores) VALUES(1,1,1,1);
```

things work as expected - a new row is inserted in the table.  If I issue the same INSERT again I get the error

> UNIQUE CONSTRAINT FAILED: biases.data,biases.link,biases.bias_type

just as expected.  I tried to use the SQLite `ON CONFLICT` clause thus

```
INSERT INTO biases (data,link,bias_type,ignores) VALUES(1,1,1,1)
ON CONFLICT(data,link,bias_type) DO UPDATE SET ignores = ignores + 1;
```

and it worked as I had hoped - instead of adding a new row or throwing up an error SQLite incremented the value of the `ignores` column in the row with the matching `data`, `link` and `bias_type` values.

However, this is just the result of an experiment.  It is not immediately clear to me from the SQLite docs that this is indeed how `ON CONFLICT` is supposed to behave - i.e it can be given two or more conflict constraints to be checked.  What I mean by two or more constraints is specifying multiple, comma separated, columns inside `CONFLICT(...)` as I have done in the example above.

I suspect that this is the right usage since I am merely specifying a `CONFLICT` condition that replicates my indicated `CONSTRAINT`. However, I cannot see this explained explicitly anywhere in the docs. I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to confirm this.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251699/sqlite-insert-or-replace-into-vs-update-where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

> UPSERT is a special syntax addition to INSERT that causes the INSERT
>   to behave as an UPDATE or a no-op if the INSERT would violate a
>   **uniqueness** constraint.

and:

> The special UPSERT processing happens only for uniqueness constraint
>   on the table that is receiving the INSERT.

So the `DO UPDATE` part is not triggered by any constraint conflict but only by a unique constraint violation.

Also:

> The syntax that occurs in between the "ON CONFLICT" and "DO" keywords
>   is called the "conflict target". The conflict target specifies a
>   **specific uniqueness constraint** that will trigger the upsert.

So it is not possible to have **two or more** conflict constraints to be checked in one statement.
However you can use separate `UPSERT` statements to check for 2 different unique constraint violations.
See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jyj4n76MZHLLk2yszB6XD/0) where I added 1 more `UNIQUE` constraint to your table:

```
CONSTRAINT con_scraps UNIQUE(scraps)
```

Comment: My question was phrased somewhat ambiguously and that resulted in you interpreting my mention of two or more conflicts incorrectly. I have now rephrased the question.

Comment: This is already mentioned in the answer: *The conflict target specifies a specific uniqueness constraint that will trigger the upsert* because *specifying multiple, comma separated, columns* refer to **1 unique constraint**

Comment: If the comma separated list of columns does not refer to a defined specific unique constraint then the code will not run with an error.