# SQLite ON CONFLICT - two or more columns

Tags: sqlite, upsert

I have the following SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bonds (a1 INTEGER,a2 INTEGER, hits INTEGER, lasthit INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY(a1,a2)) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

For every unique a1-a2 pair there will ever be only one entry - `PRIMARY KEY(a1,a2)` imposes that constraint.

Now consider the following UPSERT

```
INSERT INTO bonds (a1,a2,hits,lasthit) 
VALUES(1,1,1,1) ON CONFLICT(a1,a2) DO UPDATE SET hits = hits + 1;
```

followed by

```
SELECT a1,a2,hits FROM bonds;
```

which returns

```
a1    a2    hits
================
1     1      1
```

Re-issuing the same `INSERT/SELECT` pair as above then yields

```
a1    a2    hits
================
1     1      2
```

which appears to suggest that the way I have written the `INSERT` statement is in fact correct.  However, I have not been able to find any examples in the SQLite documentation on how to use the `ON CONFLICT` clause with 2+ columns.  Is my way, `ON CONFLICT(a1,a2)` correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct and you can use it similarly with more than 2 columns if there is a unique constraint for the combination of these columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of a separate UPSERT statements to check for 2 different unique constraint violations

```
INSERT INTO biases (data,link,bias_type,ignores,scraps) VALUES(1,1,1,1,100);

SELECT * FROM biases;

INSERT INTO biases (data,link,bias_type,ignores,scraps) VALUES(1,1,1,1,100)
ON CONFLICT(data,link,bias_type) DO UPDATE SET ignores = ignores + 1;

SELECT * FROM biases;

INSERT INTO biases (data,link,bias_type,ignores,scraps) VALUES(1,1,1,1,100)
ON CONFLICT(scraps) DO UPDATE SET ignores = ignores + 1;

SELECT * FROM biases;
```

I don't know if this helps found this here --> [Correct usage of the SQLite ON CONFLICT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287095/correct-usage-of-the-sqlite-on-conflict-clause)

Comment: The answer you have quoted is from @forpas who has commented above.  For clarity - the `CONFLICT` cause can refer to columns from a previously defined `CONSTRAINT` which can impose a **multi-column** constraint.  What you cannot do is use a `CONFLICT` clause that refers to mixed columns from different constraints.