# Upsert (INSERT ... ON CLONFLICT ... DO UPDATE) failing

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE "tests" (
"testId"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"testUser"  INTEGER UNIQUE,
"testName"  INTEGER UNIQUE
);
```

Simple upsert works :

```
INSERT INTO tests (testUser,testName)
VALUES (2,5)
ON CONFLICT (testUser) 
DO UPDATE SET testUser=2, testName=5
```

But I have two `UNIQUE` columns and need to trigger `UPDATE` upon conflict in either `testUser` or `testName`. Therefore, I need to check them both in the `ON CONFLICT` part:

```
INSERT INTO tests (testUser,testName)
VALUES (2,9)
ON CONFLICT (testUser, testName)
DO UPDATE SET testUser=2, testName=9
```

Above SQL command fails with:

> ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/XFzYTk43) with combinations I tried.

1. What is wrong? Can't we have multiple unique `ON CONFLICT` columns in upsert queries?
2. Is there any other way (apart from `REPLACE INTO`) to achieve the upsert result?

I could potentially use `REPLACE INTO`, but have foreign key constrains that cause havoc in another table upon `DELETE` executed by `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: create a unique index made up of all the columns you want to check for conflict -- ie `testUser` and `testName`

Comment: Your SQL makes no sense; you insert two values into a table and then say if those values are already there, to update them. Surely, if the values are already there then they do not need updating!

Comment: This question was originally tagged with PostgradSQL, but now is tagged with SQLlite, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287095/correct-usage-of-the-sqlite-on-conflict-clause) should be helpful to you.

Comment: @Martin Please check DBFIDDLE if it does not make sense to you. One user can only do one test. If a row with testUser=2 already exists, then there is a conflict and normal INSERT would fail. This is why I am trying to UPSERT. Also, SQLite uses PostgreSQL's syntax for upsert queries. Hence the I used both tags; this question was never tagged 'PostgradSQL' as you suggested (whatever that is).

Comment: *postgresql was the tag. Anyway, no matter. Using DBFiddle is fine but it's best to post the SQL directly in the question rather than on any 3rd party sites :)

Comment: @Martin Could you then suggest the SQL command for index on `testUser` and `testName`. I have just tried it and, unfortunately, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

the error is very clear.

with `ON CONFLICT (testUser, testName)`you need a combined UNIQUE or combined primary key.

like in the sample

```
CREATE TABLE "tests" (
    "testId"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "testUser"  INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "testName"  INTEGER UNIQUE,
  UNIQUE("testName" ,"testUser")
);
INSERT INTO tests (testUser,testName) 
  VALUES (2,3);
  
  INSERT INTO tests (testUser,testName)
  VALUES (2,9)
  ON CONFLICT (testUser, testName) 
  DO UPDATE SET testUser=2, testName=9
```

Comment: Just checked SQLIte documentation and defining `"testName"  INTEGER UNIQUE` seems to do same thing as adding `UNIQUE("testName"` in the last row of `CREATE TABLE` command. Anyhow, your suggestion does not seem to work.

Comment: run the code in a fiddle for example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/ your message is gone of course 2 exists alredy, so the "other" constraint will be triggered

Comment: Yes, I tired it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMZehLrcoaJ7hBuynH4X9J/1). You are right that `ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint` is not triggered any more, but the query still fails. So this does not solve my problem. I would like to do UPDATE when there is conflict in `testUser` OR `testName`

Comment: your problem is you have to **many unique keys**, but that isn't the problem you asked for with your error message

Comment: Thanks nbk. I edited the question slightly to reflect the issue better. I thought this was a simple problem though: one user can only run one test at the time. Therefore, two unique columns. Analogous MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works just fine with same db structure. Unfortunately, I need to use SQLIte.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Sqlite version 3.35.0 you can have multiple ON CONFLICT clauses and a DO UPDATE resolution without a conflict target in SQLite version 3.35.0 (2021-03-12).
So you can either write your command as:

```
INSERT INTO tests (testUser,testName)
VALUES (2,9)
ON CONFLICT (testUser)
DO UPDATE SET testUser=2, testName=9
ON CONFLICT (testName)
DO UPDATE SET testUser=2, testName=9
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tests (testUser,testName)
VALUES (2,9)
ON CONFLICT
DO UPDATE SET testUser=2, testName=9
```

Note that to test it in DBFIDDLE you need to select a sqlite version greater than 3.35.0