# How to do a insert or replace when the primary key will not be used

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite database on a multi device android system that requires UUID (yes it requires them), however I do not set the UUID as the primary key, instead the UUID is just a column and the primary key is just an INTEGER on each device (that is not transferred) but instead auto generated on the local android database

I am doing an Update (if failed) insert routine based on if the UUID exists -which is quite slow and eventually I want to convert this into a bulk system with the SQLITESTATEMENT

however in order for me to get to that point I need to make the INSERT OR REPLACE (or REPLACE INTO) work with my data set - From what I understand it only works based on if the primary key already exists - since my primary key is not what I actually care about how do I make the Replace Into work based of a different column?
Or perhaps I can do bulk inserts a different way - that does not involve replace intos - but can still handle inserts or updates -

any help is appreciated

Some of the items I have been using for references
[How do I UPDATE a row in a table or INSERT it if it doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690632/how-do-i-update-a-row-in-a-table-or-insert-it-if-it-doesnt-exist)

http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2013/01/sqlite-insert-or-replace-through-contentprovider/

[Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite)

[How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#execute()
[Android SQLite database: slow insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INSERT OR REPLACE` even if the UUID is not the primary key as long as you make the UUID field `UNIQUE`;

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  uuid UUID UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Any insert that violates the `UNIQUE` constraint replaces the existing row (but generates a new primary key for the new row)

[A very simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b8af8/1).

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for - Thank you for that SQLfiddle as well - a handy tool... This leads to another question but related - would I use this to execute this call? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29

Comment: @morty346 I've not used that very method, but yes, it certainly looks like the correct method to use.