# MySQL Insert or Update (Where 2 columns match)

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like below (like dummy data below).

```
RecordId | UserId | TestId | Score
----------------------------------
   1     |   1    |    4   |  98
   2     |   1    |    5   |  92
   3     |   1    |    6   |  91
   4     |   2    |    4   |  99
   5     |   2    |    5   |  07
   6     |   2    |    6   |  08
```

I want to `update` the above but I don't have the `RecordId` handy.
So lets say `UserId 2` on `TestId 5` got a `Score 55`.

We don't currently know wether a record even exists for `UserId 2` on `TestId 5` so it needs to add the data if it doesn't already exist. If The UserId and TestId do already exist I need to update them.

I don't 'think' i want to use any of the `replace` queries as I have read that these delete the old record and a create new one, which would have a new Id.

I 'think' it needs to be `update` with a `on duplicate update` but i cannot get this to work?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show your attempt.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Have read that page. Was trying this which look correct from what I read.
`UPDATE test SET Score=55 WHERE UserId=2 AND TestId=5 LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Read that link again,there is a specific syntax, doesnt start with update.

Comment: INSERT INTO + ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Comment: This may also work: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I UPDATE a row in a table or INSERT it if it doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690632/how-do-i-update-a-row-in-a-table-or-insert-it-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 3):

Ok so here is the answer.
Turns out my query was fine but i needed to create a `unique key`

Here is the prepared SQL statement I used.

```
INSERT INTO test (UserId, TestId, Score) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UserId=? TestId=? Score=?;
```

To make this update when unique combination of `UserId` & `TestId` I used the follow SQL query.

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE KEY `UserTests` (`UserId`, `TestId`);
```

I hope this & my explanation helps someone out.