# Inserted rows are not actually inserted

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I am downloading some data over network in JSON format and after retrieving it, I am storing it in SqlLiteDatabase. Earlier I use to fetch the data and display it in RecyclerView but now I am storing it in SqlLite Database and then displaying it in RecyclerView. However the data get stored successfully as it return true but when I display the data, it shows nothing. To check if the data exist or not after being added, I get the number of count on available data and it returns 0.

Here are the codes:

```
public boolean create(List<PGCardItemReturn> objectPg) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    PGCardItemReturn lastItem = null;;
    db.beginTransaction();
    String sql = "Insert or Replace into tenant_pg (id,furnishing,area,price,numberofbeds,image_url) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement(sql);
    for(int i=0;i<objectPg.size();i++){
        PGCardItemReturn item = objectPg.get(i);
        if(i == (this.count()-1)){
            lastItem = item;
        }
        insert.bindString(1, item.getId());
        insert.bindString(2, item.getFurnishing());
        insert.bindString(3, item.getArea());
        insert.bindString(4, item.getPrice());
        insert.bindString(5, item.getNumberofbeds());
        insert.bindString(6, item.getImageUrl());

        insert.execute();
    }



    db.endTransaction();



    return true;
}
```

In Main Acvitiy:

```
boolean add = new TableControllerTenant_pg(getApplicationContext()).create(listPG);
```

Comment: so you are saying your insert works but your display does not, and then you post the code that is working - I am confused.

Comment: check your database file to be sure that data is inserted in database or not

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690632/how-do-i-update-a-row-in-a-table-or-insert-it-if-it-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling [beginTransaction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29).
Its documentation says:

> The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling [setTransactionSuccessful](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful%28%29)).

Comment: Thank you so much. How idiot of me to not include that! I almost forgot. Thanks!