# SQLite instability in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

To upsert a record I check in database wether record already exist. If not `INSERT` ootherwise `UPDATE` is performed. But sometimes fetching record goes wrong, and even record exist **it does not find any**. Why? How can it happen?

DB is modified only in this method.

```
11-04 13:08:34.542 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column _id is not unique (code 19)
11-04 13:08:34.548 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
11-04 13:08:34.550 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:779)
11-04 13:08:34.551 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
11-04 13:08:34.553 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
11-04 13:08:34.554 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at com.j4nos.moviebuffs.Utility$2.run(Utility.java:360)
11-04 13:08:34.556 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-04 13:08:34.557 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-04 13:08:34.558 20181-20248/com.j4nos.moviebuffs W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

---

`public static ExecutorService serialQueue = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`

```
public static void upsert(final JSONObject record) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public synchronized void run() {

                try {
                    String recordType = record.getString("recordType");
                    String id = record.getString("_id");

                    Boolean recordExist = true;
                    Cursor cursor3 = Utility.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + recordType + " WHERE _id = '" + id + "'", null);
                    if (cursor3.getCount() == 0) {
                        recordExist = false;
                    }
                //.....
            }
        };


    Utility.serialQueue.execute(runnable);
}
```

Comment: Or you could simply take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690632/how-do-i-update-a-row-in-a-table-or-insert-it-if-it-doesnt-exist For your problem, using Runnable might be the problem. Are you reading a JSonArray ? SO multiple inserts ? Meaning multiple thread maybe ?

Comment: And did you synchronize anything ? If two threads tried to upsert the same id, you might run into problem if both check if it exist, then try to insert in the same time.

Comment: `upsert` can be called from different threads, but code is executed on a serial queue. All DB operation are performed only on `serialQueue`. So theoretically no sync problem could arise. Do you agree @AxelH?

Comment: Since you use a fixed thread pool of size 1, it should not. But to be sure, I would synchronize the block (from the select query to the insert or update). Just to see if this is the cause

Comment: `and even record exist it does not find any` Are you sure that your `_id` column is a **TEXT** field? Because you are trying to compare it to a **String** (`" WHERE _id = '" + id + "'"`).

Comment: Hey @Rotwang! `_id` is `VARCHAR`: `CREATE TABLE Rating(_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, item VARCHAR, userSetting VARCHAR, scale BOOLEAN)`

Comment: @AxelH I put in `synchronized` still same phenomenon. Tried do a DELETE and then an INSERT. Same phenomenon.

Comment: Could you add the insert query ?

Comment: I think I have and idea ... what is the length of _id VARCHAR ? Is it possible that you have some truncated values here ? Meaning that you search for `foobar` but only insert `fooba` because the column is only 5 character.