# Multiple column update between two table with 'SET' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables as below.

**Tabel A:**

```
        ResultID(PK) | ImportDate | Comment1
        -------------------------------------
        101          | 25-09-2019 | One
        --------------------------------------
        102          | 25-09-2019 | Two
        --------------------------------------
        103          | 25-09-2019 | Three
        ----------------------------------------
```

**Table B:**

```
        ResultID(PK) | ImportDate | Comment2
        -------------------------------------
        101          | 26-09-2019 | new one
        --------------------------------------
        104          | 26-09-2019 | four
        --------------------------------------
```

So the output should look like

**Table A:**

```
ResultID(PK) | ImportDate | Comment1
-------------------------------------
101          | 26-09-2019 | new one
--------------------------------------
102          | 25-09-2019 | Two
--------------------------------------
103          | 25-09-2019 | Three
--------------------------------------
104          | 26-09-2019 | four
--------------------------------------
```

**Question:**
I want to get resulting Table A as mentioned above if `ResultID` is matched between Table A and Table B, I want to update all column in Table A from Table B for that `ResultID`. If `ResultID` from Table B is not present in Table A, insert it to Table A.

**What I have tried in MySQL:**

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET comment1=
(SELECT comment2 FROM TableB WHERE TableA.ResultId=TableB.ResultId);
```

Above solution only works for one column to update Table A. I also tried with multiple column update reference from 
[SQL Server 2005 implementation of MySQL REPLACE INTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234/sql-server-2005-implementation-of-mysql-replace-into) but multiple column update is not working for my scenarios.

For my real scenarios- I have 40 columns and 50,000 rows.

Could you please provide me any hint or solution? Thank you.

Comment: I think you are trying to get away from including the 40 columns, but unless you are doing dynamic sql you are out of luck. Just add the 40 columns, using one of the solutions shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a primary key on `ResultID`, you can simply use an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query to transfer *all* the data from `TableB` to `TableA`:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ResultID, ImportDate, Comment1)
SELECT ResultID, ImportDate, Comment2 FROM TableB
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  ImportDate = VALUES(ImportDate),
  Comment1 = VALUES(Comment1);
```

Output:

```
ResultID    ImportDate  Comment1
101         26-09-2019  new one
102         25-09-2019  Two
103         25-09-2019  Three
104         26-09-2019  four
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4QiNcGsrLVkhNXBPkhx8mD/0)

Comment: Is there any way we can find the same output when ResultId is not a primary key?

Comment: @Jay it's a lot more complicated. Can you possibly make `ResultId` a unique key (it doesn't have to be the primary key).